# Elasticsearch re-index

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

My content (from a database) is read into an elasticsearch search index initially via a full index which stores the db record data into a class and then adds each class instance into the index that has been created.

My question is how would i do an incremental index...

i want to have a job run every set amount of time and any records it finds in the db that have been updated in that time i want them to be reindexed...

i cant just use the

client.Index(mycontent)

as the full index uses as this will add another copy of this record to the index...

can anyone advise how i just update a selected number of records already in the index from the amended db records that they correrspond to ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic here , you will need to maintain some kind of timestamp field which is updated whenever a insertion or change happens to the row. Also make sure the primary key is made as the document ID , that way updated documents are over written and not created as duplicates.

I would recommend [this JDBC importer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc) written by 
Jörg Prante.

In README , he has explained the incremental usage using the following -

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : [
            {
                "statement" : "select * from \"products\" where \"mytimestamp\" > ?",
                "parameter" : [ "$metrics.lastexecutionstart" ]
            }
        ],
        "index" : "my_jdbc_index",
        "type" : "my_jdbc_type"
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks im using a C# windows form solution... im recognising the row changed with a check in the stored procedure which then returns the row or rows of records that have been updated in this set period.

Comment: are you referring to making the elasticsearch _id the same as my own designated id in my class poco ?